# How to terminate CircleCI after running tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, circleci

My test passes as good as expected but the process hangs on the running status! is it a side effect of the background process? how to solve this problem?

[image]

(I need to run nodeJs as a background process to testing my app)

my config file:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@1.1.6
jobs:
  build-and-run:
    executor:
      name: node/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/with-cache:
          steps:
            - run: npm install
            - run:
                name: initial run
                command: npm run start-server-for-test && sleep 5
                background: true
            - run: npm run ci-test

workflows:
    build-and-run:
      jobs:
        - build-and-run
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't looks like a CircleCI error. Run this same commands in your machine and try if it works. Also you can run jobs with ssh enabled in CircleCI and login to the machine and execute the commands, in that way you could troubleshoot.